# How do I map markdown headings onto LaTeX headings?

Tags: pandoc, markdown

When I run my markdown file through Pandoc, this line...

`# First Book: The Person`

becomes...

`\section{First Book: The Person}\label{first-book-the-person}}`

What I want is...

`\part{First Book: The Person}\label{first-book-the-person}}`

...but I can't find information on how to map a sequence of hashtags onto a different LaTeX heading than the default.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/52969876

Comment: This worked perfectly on the first try. Thanks!

Comment: I'm happy if I could be of help. However, if you want to say ‘thanks’, in the spirit of this site, it's more helpful to up-vote what you find useful. For example, you can up-vote my comment and/or [Fran's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/688885/262081) and/or accept Fran's answer (if it’s answer your question of course). In this way you indicate to future visitors the relevant content with regard to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem, linked in the comment, is that you do not specify the `top-level-division`, but another is that the top level in your converted document is `\section`, and therefore you are converting to the default `article` document class, or using a custom template, or a document class option to convert to some other article-like document class.

In classes where `\chapter` is not defined, you cannot rise the top level division, since including this command you will obtain a  "undefined control sequence" fatal error. Therefore, the easiest solution is use a book-like document class where this command exist. With quarto markdown, a MWE could be:

```
---
format: pdf
toc: true
toc-depth: 6
top-level-division: part
documentclass: book
---

# Foo1
Text 

## Foo2
Text 

### Foo3
Text 

#### Foo4
Text 

##### Foo5
Text 

###### Foo6
Text 

####### Foo7
Text
```

Note 1: Although the ToC depth is 6, it will show the 7 levels because the optional part level is 0, not 1.

Note 2: If you want the 7 levels, but with the article-like layout, both `memoir` a `scrbook` classes have options for that.